# JTable fireTableDataChanged() method doesn't refresh table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

After adding a row I expected JTable to be refreshed. 
Unfortunately it is not.

My code is like that:

How I add a row:

```
JButton btnDodaj = new JButton("Dodaj");`

panel.add(btnDodaj);

btnDodaj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Na pewno chcesz dodac nowy rekord?",
                "wybieraj", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            return;
        }
        dbHelper.dodajOsoba(editPaneName.getText(), editPaneNazw.getText(), formattedDataUr.getText(),
                (Enum) comboBoxStCyw.getSelectedItem(), (String) comboBoxZaw.getSelectedItem(),
                (String) comboBoxMia.getSelectedItem(), textFieldPesel.getText());
        simpleTableDemo.model.fireTableDataChanged();

    }
});
```

How I add simpleTableDemo to JPanel:

```
simpleTableDemo = new ListaOsob();
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, simpleTableDemo, 100, SpringLayout.SOUTH, comboBoxMia);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, simpleTableDemo, 33, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, simpleTableDemo, 617, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
panel.add(simpleTableDemo);
```

Definition of SimpleTableDemo:

```
Object[][] data2 = dbHelper.wyswietlOsoba();
model = new DefaultTableModel(data2, columnNames);
table = new JTable(model);
```

EDIT:

My dodajOsoba method:

```
try {
        sql = "INSERT INTO osoba1 (imie, nazwisko, dataUrodzenia, stanCywilny, zawod, miasto, pesel) VALUES ('" + imie
                + "', '" + nazwisko + "','" + dataUrodzenia + "','" + stanCywilny + "','" + zawod + "','" + miasto
                + "','" + pesel +"');";
        ListaOsob lista = new ListaOsob();
        lista.model.addRow(new Object[]{imie, nazwisko, dataUrodzenia, stanCywilny,zawod,miasto,pesel});

        stmt.execute(sql);

    }
```

Row is added correctly but the JTable is not refreshing.

What did i miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't tell what is wrong based on the code provide. All we can do is guess:

1. We have no idea what the `dodajOsoba` method does although it is almost certainly wrong. If you want to change the data being displayed in the table then you need to update the data in the `TableModel` directly. So your code should be using the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add a new row of data.
2. You should never invoke `fireTableDataChanged()` in your application code. It is the job of the TableModel to invoke that method. The `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` will invoke the appropriate method for you.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I moved addRow method to functionality of 'Dodaj' button and i works perfectly. Thanks man!